# Universe as 3D projective space?

Tags: galaxy, universe

Is there any benefit to view the 3D (real) universe as 3D projective space?

Comment: I suggested closing this as opinion based, but it's also somewhat vague (you would strictly speaking need to supply a detailed theory to replace and compare with existing theories).  As GR works well (4 dimensions) and replacements in e.g. string theory use as many as 26 dimensions, that's a tall order and beyond the scope of an SE to deal with IMO.